# Mysql trigger no error message but code not working

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I wrote this trigger in phpMyAdmin

```
BEGIN
DECLARE start DATETIME;
DECLARE now DATETIME;
DECLARE date DATETIME;

SELECT `starting` INTO start FROM events WHERE events.id = NEW.event_id;
SET now = NOW();
SET date = CURDATE();

IF start > now THEN

    IF DATE(start) = date THEN
        SET @hours = HOUR(start - now);
        IF @hours <= 1 THEN
            SET @text = 'in less than an hour';
        ELSE
            SET @text = CONCAT('in about ', @hours, ' hours');
        END IF;

        INSERT INTO notifications (user_id, subject, action_id, data, seen, activates)
        VALUES (NEW.user_id, NEW.event_id, 2, CONCAT('{"period":"', @text, '"}'), 0, now);

    ELSE

        INSERT INTO notifications (user_id, subject, action_id, data, seen, activates)
        VALUES 
            (NEW.user_id, NEW.event_id, 2, '{"period":"tomorrow"}', 0, DATE(start - INTERVAL 1 DAY)),
            (NEW.user_id, NEW.event_id, 2, '{"period":"in one hour"}', 0, start - INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
    END IF;
END IF;
END
```

The purpose of it is to create notifications about a starting event when a user submits that he is going to be attending an event. The trigger works if the event is not today, but if the event is today I get this message

> Column data cannot be NULL

Column data is in table `notifications`. If the event is set to start today I get column data cannot be NULL, if the event is further in future, like tomorrow I get accurate message.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: if @text is null, then @hours must be null - sql nulls are contagious, which probably means `start` is null in your first query where you actually set `start`, from which `@hours` is based.

Comment: @MarcB I just checked, by replacing `@text` inside the `INSERT` statement with respectively `start` and `now`, I determined that `start` is equal to `2014-11-21 20:00:00` and `now` is equal to '2014-11-21 19:29:31' at the time of testing. For some reason `HOUR(start - now)` is returning NULL, I don't understand..

Comment: I'm uncertain what the datatype of `start - now` should be, but my quick read of the docs suggests possibly some numeric type.  In any case, it should not be `DATE`, `TIME`, or `DATETIME`.  It seems unlikely that the `HOUR()` function will do anything useful with that.

Comment: shouldn't that be `= HOUR(start) - HOUR(now)`?

Comment: `datetime-datetime` will return a float of some sort. hour(float) should return just `1`. store the result of your subtraction somewhere before you apply hour().

Answer (score 0):

There was something wrong with this bit of code

```
HOUR(start - now)
```

I replaced it with

```
HOUR(TIMEDIFF(start - now))
```

Now everything works as expected.

I got to solve the problem with [Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b)'s [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066604/mysql-trigger-no-error-message-but-code-not-working/27071221#comment42647092_27066604) for which I thank him and everyone else who commented!